# Need to filter out conditional values from MySql table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, having

I stuck with this kind of scenario wherein I need to extract the IDs based on this logic.

In this example, I want to extract the following combination in the output:

- INCLUDE the result if:

1. source has one or more combinations of - Raja, Ravi or Sam

And

- Exclude the ID if:

1. Source has one or more combinations of - Jane, Jake, or Jude.

| ID | Source |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Raja |
| 1 | Ravi |
| 2 | Sam |
| 2 | Raja |
| 3 | Jake |
| 3 | Raja |
| 3 | Sam |
| 3 | Jane |
| 4 | Sam |
| 4 | Jake |
| 4 | Jude |

Output, I'm expecting as:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

This source table will always have more than 1 source value for each id.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use aggregation and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT ID
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(Source IN ('Raja', 'Ravi', 'Sam')) > 0
   AND SUM(Source IN ('Jane', 'Jake', 'Jude')) = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8808060b7ab58030f45951cb8c572cdb).

Comment: This seem to be working as expected. Could you pls explain how the SUM is working here with > and = 0. Thanks.

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta `Source IN ('Raja', 'Ravi', 'Sam')` and `Source IN ('Jane', 'Jake', 'Jude')` are boolean expressions that are evaluated as 1 for true and 0 for false. So SUM sums all the 1s, meaning it counts only when each boolean expression is true.

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta when `SUM(Source IN ('Raja', 'Ravi', 'Sam'))` is `> 0` it means that for this ID there is at least 1 row with Source in the list. When `SUM(Source IN ('Jane', 'Jake', 'Jude'))` is `= 0` it means that for this ID there is no row with Source in the list.

Comment: out of curiosity, can you share what I might be doing wrong with this?

select ID from Table T GROUP BY ID
where (
(Source = 'Ravi' AND Source = 'Raja')
OR
(Source = 'Ravi' AND Source = 'Sam')
OR
(Source = 'Raja' AND Source = 'Sam')
OR
(Source = 'Ravi' AND Source = 'Raja' AND Source = 'Sam')
)
AND Source NOT IN ('Jake', 'Jane', 'Jude')

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta I don't know what you are trying to do but each of the expressions: `(Source = '....' AND Source = '....')` returns FALSE because Source can't be  'Ravi' and 'Raja' in the same row.

Comment: Yea, that is what I thought too.
In the correct solution that you provided, we are first grouping at the ID level, ID 1 let's say, and then checking in available sources against ID, that is Raja and Ravi.. so that is satisfying the first condition and then checking for =0  case too in the same source list, that is also satisfied, hence it returned us the ID as 1.
Is my understanding correct here?
Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta yes, this is why there are 2 conditions in the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 0):

a good example to use EXISTS and NOT EXISTS.

Here is a way to do this

```
select distinct t.id
  from table t
where exists (select 1
                from table t2
               where t2.id=t.id
                 and t2.name in ('Raja','Ravi','Sam')
 and not exists(select 1
                  from table t3
                 where t3.id=t.id
                   and t3.name in ('Jane','Jake','Jude')
                )
```